# How to add vertices loops around holes in a mesh

Tags: mesh

HELP , trying to learn how to add vertices loops around holes in a mesh
or maybe the proper term is edge loops ,
for some armor Im trying to make , can anyone tell me where to find 
info on how to do this ? Dont seem to understand what mesh tool to use to do this.
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1-CGZm1Y9k59X2WeGsTIFEbw5e2Vk1n

[image]

Comment: can you add more explanation of what you need to do?

Comment: am trying to close the verts and add beveled edges , because if I use an MH model to make the armor its not an issue but if I use anything else everything turns into a spiky mess and becomes unusable forcing. me to start from scratch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this might work for you... select the egde loops with <kbd>alt</kbd> <kbd>right click</kbd> [image] press <kbd>F</kbd> to create a face[image] press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>t</kbd> to triangulate [image] press <kbd>alt</kbd> <kbd>j</kbd> to untriangulate [image] and then delete those front faces there that you have created (the 3 quads in this case) that you wont need. spam: a model in progress lol https://gamebanana.com/wips/49759